# Is there an equivalent of GetModuleFileName() for Linux and how would I use it?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi, getmodulefilename, dladdr

I have a function on Windows to get the address of the module in buf:

```
GetModuleFileName(0, buf, buf_size);
```

I want to do the same on Linux (which I do not know much about). I found the function `dladdr(X, &dlInfo)` which seems to do the right thing. As I understand I get the name and other details (`dli_sname`, `dli_saddr`, `dli_fname`, ..) of `X` in `dlInfo` with this function.

But what is `X`?  I know it it an address. But which one?  How would I use this to obtain the same result as on Windows?

Comment: this does not get the address of "the module", it gets the filename of the program that is running. Perhaps you are looking for the virtual file `/proc/self/exe`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  We're working in a bit of a vacuum here.

Comment: *"address of the module"* - Which module, specifically? A process generally has more than one module loaded. Also, `GetModuleFileName` doesn't return the (load) address of a module. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

`X` is any interesting address, usually the address of an interesting module function. If you want to get the current module name, `X` can be an address of the caller

```
void X() {
  // ... 
  dladdr(X, &dlInfo);
  // or dladdr(&X, &dlInfo);
}
```